# How to disable dumprep.exe

Tags: windows

Dumprep.exe always hangs the system, is there any way to disable it so that applications can crash (or I can force close them) peacefully?

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://www.eddieoneverything.com/windows-xp/how-to-disable-dumprepexe-dump-reporting-tool-on-windows-xp.php) method works?

Comment: Is dumprep.exe actually causing the hang, or is it the result of a hung app? dumprep normally runs when an application has crashed or hung.

Comment: Crashed app closes and leaves dumprep running, it uses most of processing power and leaves nothing for me to work on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How to disable dumprep.exe:**
>
> 1. Right click on “My Computer,” choose “Properties” from that menu.
> 2. Click on “Advanced tab,”  Click the “Error Reporting” button.
> 3. Check the “Disable error reporting” box. 
>      You may choose to uncheck the the box below it, “But notify me when an error occurs,” if desired.
>
> Voila, the annoying dumprep.exe tool is now disabled!

Reference: http://www.eddieoneverything.com/windows-xp/how-to-disable-dumprepexe-dump-reporting-tool-on-windows-xp.php